# A technology building set that is not LEGO Technic, K'NEX, or Meccano. Can you help me with the name?

Tags: part-identification

I remember a building/technology set from years ago and I'm trying to recall its name.

The parts were plastic and could be joined by slots down their sides. A stud on the end of other pieces fitted into the slot and could slide along.

The set also had pneumatic components.

Here is a sketch of my best memory of a typical brick.

[image]

Can you name it for me?

Comment: That's a really neat sketch from memory, well done.

Comment: Thanks. Done with the old 2D Microsoft Paint!  Only real error was I forgot to show the ends of the hidden slots - Grrr.

Comment: Great, now you've reminded me of  my childhood loves:   Girder& Panel and the companion Bridge& Turnpike;   and ErectorSets.  Turns out the former is still being manufactured!  The latter, in a modified form, is Meccano

Comment: You got the actual answer but my first inclination was to say "that's T-slot aluminum!  That's not a toy, it's real engineering system!"  Of course what you are describing actually is the toy; but the version with aluminum beams and metal or plastic brackets exists too, and is used to make somewhat similar real-world constructions.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - Fischer Technik is actually sometimes used for prototyping  and they make longer compatible beams of  aluminium   -  https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/113988075590?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-153316-527457-8&mkcid=2&itemid=113988075590&targetid=4585032211933600&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=&poi=&campaignid=398226948&mkgroupid=1302921513642151&rlsatarget=pla-4585032211933600&abcId=2145997&merchantid=87779&msclkid=27b055c5ba741c56a89c0aa49bed7d71

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on your description, this sounds like [Fischertechnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischertechnik):

[image: Fischertechnik element]

[image: Fischertechnik set]

Comment: That's it - Thanks

Comment: Definitely Fischertechnik. Used to be quite popular, next to Meccano.

Comment: Very popular in Germany, used not only by hobbyists, but also by professionals building functional models of industrial equipment.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Being able to build functional models is part of the idea behind it. Fisher is a big company in plastic extrusion and molding technology. (Most people probably know them best from plugs for screws, washers and other plastic fasteners). They originally made the first FisherTechnic set in 1964 partly as a technology demo and partly as a Christimas customer relations gift. It proved to be so popular it became a separate business division.

Comment: I owned a set in the 1970s. They are fun and high quality -- these bricks are made from nylon.